# Return output of the function executed 'on_click'

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

How to get the output of the function executed `on_click` by `ipywidgets.Button` 
 outside the function to use in next steps? For example, I want to get back the value of `a` after every click to use in the next cell of the jupyter-notebook. So far I only get `None`.

```
from ipywidgets import Button
def add_num(ex):
    a = b+1
    print('a = ', a)
    return a

b = 1
buttons = Button(description="Load/reload file list")
a = buttons.on_click(add_num)
display(buttons)
print(a)
```

Comment: For someone struggling like me, declaring `global a` solves the problem. Not the most elegant solution. but that's how I got through it.

Comment: while declaring a global may work for this type of problem I'd advise against doing that for a mutable variable checkout the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil) for more on why not to use globals.

Comment: I know drawbacks of using global, agree with you completely.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The best way that I have found to do this type of thing is by creating a subclass of `widgets.Button` and then add a new `traitlet` attribute . That way you can load the value(s) that you want to perform operations on when you create a new button object. You can access this new `traitlet` attribute whenever you want **inside** or **outside** of the function. Here is an example;

```
from ipywidgets import widgets
from IPython.display import display
from traitlets import traitlets

class LoadedButton(widgets.Button):
    """A button that can holds a value as a attribute."""

    def __init__(self, value=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LoadedButton, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # Create the value attribute.
        self.add_traits(value=traitlets.Any(value))

def add_num(ex):
    ex.value = ex.value+1
    print(ex.value)

lb = LoadedButton(description="Loaded", value=1)
lb.on_click(add_num)
display(lb)
```

[image: loaded button example screenshot]
Hope that helps. Please comment below if this does not solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks! It did solve the problem. This is in fact only a sample problem, the real problem has a dictionary of widgets (checkboxes) which were loaded `on_click`. But, I could pass the complete dictionary through `values`, so it all worked perfectly.

Comment: Seems complicated for just returning a value. Has this been improved since?